# MySQL SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() for compound key. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id, compound-key

Can I get the LAST INSERT ID() for a compound key in MySQL?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  You can't have multiple auto-increment fields in a single table.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id1 int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  id2 int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id1, id2)
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (DEFAULT, 2);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- returns 1, the value generated for id1
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the value only for a column declared `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  There's no function to return the value in a compound primary key that *wasn't* generated by the system.  You ought to know that value already, since you just gave it in an `INSERT` statement.  The tricky case would be when a trigger or something overrides the value.

Comment: "You can't have multiple auto-increment fields in a single table." I did not know this, so I tried to create a table with two auto-increment fields, and I got this error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

Comment: So, 7 years later, the answer holds.