# How to get last inserted ID after insert to MySQL table with multi col primary key

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Id1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id3` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id4` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id1`,`Id2`,`Id3`,`Id4`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

INSERT INTO `test` (`Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'test')
INSERT INTO `test` (`Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'test2')
INSERT INTO `test` (`Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 2, 1, 'test')
INSERT INTO `test` (`Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 2, 1, 'test2')
```

After creating the table the date looks like this:

```
Id1   Id2   Id3   Id4   Name

1     1     1     1     test
1     1     1     2     test2
1     2     1     1     test
1     2     1     2     test2
```

Id4 is incrementing as is expected but I have problem to get inserted Id4 using PHP mysqli. This is the code I am using:

```
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$db->query("INSERT INTO `test` (`Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'test')");
var_dump($db->insert_id);
```

I get result

```
int(0)
```

Result should be `int(1)` but I get zero for no reason. Any ideas?

Comment: can you add `AUTO_INCREMENT=1` to the end of `create table` (after 'DYNAMIC') and give it a new try?

Comment: @Fred-ii- But this is exactly what he just did and it didn't work for him... or am i missing something? He is using the  Object Oriented Style which is synonymous with what you just posted for the Procedural Style.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: He does have a column that has the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, doesn't he?

Comment: *"My problem is to get Id4 after row insert."* - There is no `Id4` in your query. Why don't you show us your real code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have a feeling that you'll have to delete this one as well.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Nope, I kind of like it there actually. As the saying goes: *"Bad publicity, is still publicity"* ;-)

Comment: I did some modifications in my question to be more specific.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above '2', say) you can be pretty much certain that your design is flawed

Comment: Enumerated column means Id1, Id2... ? This is just an example. My actual cols have different names that make sense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense This question is duplicate to what? I am not able to find any other question like this on stackoverflow. Can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, your code should work... it worked when  tested... in other words check to see if there is something else going on... as it stands, your code is ok.... and should work fine... However as an alternative work-around, you may want to wrap MySql LAST_INSERT_ID() Function in your own Function and then call the Function when you need to get the Last Insert ID...

```
    <?php 

    // WILL RETURN THE ID OF THE AUTO-INCREMENTED FIELD ONLY
    function getLastInsertID($db, $tbl='test'){
        $result = null;
        $sql    = $db->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM `". $tbl ."`");
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->bind_result($result);
        $sql->fetch();
        return $result;
    }
    var_dump(getLastInsertID($db));
```

Perhaps it does the Trick for you....

REF: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: What's wrong with mysqli API function?

Comment: @YourCommonSense      Only common sense, man! Sometimes it can be very Uncommon

Comment: Thanks. This solve my problem. $mysqli->insert_id return 0 while actual SQL request returns correct value. It looks like there is really something wrong with API function.

Comment: @sajushko  Good! Happy it worked for you. The Problem could stem from a lot of causes especially in this case but Nice it worked. You may just mark this as the Answer so that anyone with a Similar issue in the Future may benefit from it...

Comment: @Poiz marked :) Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  ***Never argue with stupid people, they will drag you down to their level & then beat you with experience.*** Ironically enough, **within the Stupid dwells the Wisest! The Grandest of Fools does in the Wisest as well dwell.** Tell me: **who can describe an Apple that has never tasted 1?** ***How can 1 recognise a Fool, without himself knowing folly?*** The Paradoxes of Life, Wisdom & Foolishness go way beyond Logic, Coding & Poetry. They are experiences which can only be tasted, known & owned: for in the Fool, the Wise waits as in the Wise the Fool mocks... **ALL IN TIME**

Comment: @YourCommonSense    Even the Lord of Sciences (Einstein) understood this: **ONLY 2 THINGS ARE INFINITE, THE UNIVERSE & HUMAN STUPIDITY. AND I'M NOT SURE ABOUT THE FORMER.** He also noted something more interesting, Quote: ***I FEAR THE DAY THAT TECHNOLOGY WILL SURPASS OUR HUMAN INTERACTION. THE WORLD WILL HAVE A GENERATION OF IDIOTS!***  Mark Twain or Einstein? ***MySqli Api Functions or simply collaborated with a Fellow to solve the issue @Hand?*** https://imgur.com/a/HeQc5

Comment: @YourCommonSense  The same solution down-voted as wrong and not following convention, was the solution to the OP's issue. In his words: ***This solve my problem. $mysqli->insert_id return 0 while actual SQL request returns correct value. It looks like there is really something wrong with API function.*** In order words, ***Maybe even gods do bleed too...*** But then, didn't Einstein just say that **Stupidity is Infinite?** - The only difference being that ***i embrace mine and thus i know no more...*** this indeed is also part of my ***COMMON SENSE***!!!

Answer (score 0):

LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value only for a column declared AUTO_INCREMENT. There's no function to return the value in a compound primary key that wasn't generated by the system. You ought to know that value already, since you just gave it in an INSERT statement. The tricky case would be when a trigger or something overrides the value.

More details:
[Check this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372388/mysql-select-last-insert-id-for-compound-key-is-it-possible)

Comment: Id4 is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Try with InnoDB. Hope it will help.

Comment: Engine is not a problem. There was problem with mysqli_insert_id function. This function returns 0 while actual LAST_INSERT_ID() request returns correct value.